# Yii migration extend custom class

Tags: php, yii, migration

```
class m150602_071107_naujassss extends CDbMigration
{
    public function up()
    {
    }

    public function down()
    {
        echo "m150602_071107_tests does not support migration down.\n";
        return false;
    }

    /*
    // Use safeUp/safeDown to do migration with transaction
    public function safeUp()
    {
    }

    public function safeDown()
    {
    }
    */
}
```

`CDbMigration` is default class to extend I need extend custom class `CustomCDbMigration`

How to do that ? Some settings in config ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create custom class for migration.

```
/protected/components or /protected/extension/db (as you wish)
class CustomMigration extends CDbMigration
{

    protected function getMyVar()
    {
        return 'Custom migration';
    }
}
```

Go to console, path to protected, execute command 'yiic migrate create test'.
Go to the generated file of migration and change to:

```
class m150602_071449_test extends CustomMigration
{
    public function up()
    {
        echo $this->getMyVar();
        die();
    }
...
```

Testing. Run in console 'yiic migrate'.

```
Apply the above migration? (yes|no) [no]:yes
*** applying m150602_071449_test
Custom migration    <------- my function
```

**For override template of migration**:

```
//console config
'components'=>array(/*...*/),
'commandMap'=>array(
        'migrate'=>array(
            'class'=>'system.cli.commands.MigrateCommand',
            'migrationPath'=>'application.migrations',
            'migrationTable'=>'tbl_migration',
            'connectionID'=>'db',
            'templateFile'=>'application.migrations.template',
        ),
  ),

//template for migrations /protected/migrations/template.php
<?php
class {ClassName} extends CustomMigration
{
    public function up()
    {
    }

    //other methods...
}
```

Check new content of migration `yiic migrate create test`. New migration will be get content from /protected/migrations/template.php

Comment: Ok, but I need that CustomMigration will be added to migration created file auto when I execute `migrate create name`

Comment: I know we can use templateFile for migrations. It is best way. But I never use this. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.migration

Comment: I updated answer. You can check new version. Hope this help you.